# c# в чем может быть ошибка преобразования unicode в utf8 текст?

Tags: c#

```
string s = "\\u0423 \\u0432\\u0430\\u0441"
Encoding.Default.GetString(Encoding.Default.GetBytes("\\u0423 \\u0432\\u0430\\u0441"));
```

c# в чем может быть ошибка преобразования unicode в utf8 текст?

В моем случае нужно посимвольно перекодировать через FOR? или есть готовое решение?

Эту строку возвращает сервер с заголовком Content-Type: charset=utf-8

Answer (score 0):

```
string unicodeEscapedString = "\\u0423 \\u0432\\u0430\\u0441";

string unicodeString = Regex.Unescape(unicodeEscapedString);

Encoding utf8 = Encoding.UTF8;
Encoding unicode = Encoding.Unicode;

//конвертим в байтовый массив
byte[] unicodeBytes = unicode.GetBytes(unicodeString);

// конвертим байты уникода в утф8
byte[] utf8Bytes = Encoding.Convert(unicode, utf8, unicodeBytes);

// Конвертим их в символы
char[] utf8Chars = new char[utf8.GetCharCount(utf8Bytes, 0, utf8Bytes.Length)];
utf8.GetChars(utf8Bytes, 0, utf8Bytes.Length, utf8Chars, 0);
string utf8String = new string(utf8Chars);
```

Comment: "\\u0423" изначально у меня текст состоит из таких 'символов', и в нужный массив байтов он не сможет это перекодировать правильно

Comment: А как заменить этот слеш? через replace не получится, 1 символ во входящей строке - 5 байтов весит а не 2 как в уникоде

Comment: \u0423 это 6 байтов в моем случае, если превраить как то в 2 байта unicode, тогда ваш вариант сработает

Comment: Regex.Unescape(unicodeString); - должно помочь